# Form only passing the single value of input array

Tags: jquery

If I create new input forms and put valid information in them, then hit submit, only the first field shows up in the `skillName[]` and `skillLevel[]` array.  I am at a complete loss here, as when I open developer tools it shows that the new fields are in fact being created with `name="skillName[]"` and `name="skillLevel[]"` which means when I do a `var_dump($_POST['skillName']);` it should return more than 1... but it is only returning 1 value, even if I fill out 3 fields.

**Easiest to show you on JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/o6p1ybw8/

Comment: This seems to be more of a PHP issue than a jQuery one. Note also that IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: You've only tagged this `jquery` - but it *appears* you are processing the values as submitted (ie in some form of server-side post handler) - please provide the details regarding the post handler.

Comment: Why you would put an `array` in the a HTML name attribute?

Comment: The fiddle just shows the dynamically generated dom nodes - it doesn't show how you submit or the submit handler.

Comment: Felix how else would I handle an unknown amount of inputs that need to use the same name attribute?

Comment: I'm working a new JSFiddle with an other PHP stuff,hope it can help you

Comment: @j08691 The PHP right now is simply a var_dump of the $_POST array.  It should contain all of them, as I am passing an array through the form.